# Not Scraping all of the requested data except for one CSS list on one page

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage, however despite giving correct CSS in Chrome inspect Selenium does not scrape all of the data it only scrapes on the odds of the first page as seen below and then gives an error message.

I have re-tested the CSS and changed it multiple times however, Selenium Python does not seem to scrape the data correctly.

I also tend to get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bain3/PycharmProjects/untitled4/Vpalmerbet1.py", line 1365, in <module>
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('.match-pop-market a[href*="/sports/soccer/"]'))))
  File "C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I have tried changing CSS as well as using xpath for:

```
#clickMe = wait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('.match-pop-market a[href*="/sports/soccer/"]'))))

clickMe = wait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ("//*[@class='match-pop-market']//a[href*='/sports/soccer/']"))))
```

You can see that chrome inspects detects this CSS

[image]

My full code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

try:
    os.remove('vtg121.csv')
except OSError:
    pass

driver.get('https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer')

#SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5


from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#clickMe = wait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//*[@id="TopPromotionBetNow"]'))))
#if driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#TopPromotionBetNow'):
    #driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#TopPromotionBetNow').click()

#last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

#while True:

    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")


    #time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)


    #new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    #if new_height == last_height:
        #break
    #last_height = new_height

time.sleep(1)

clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//*[contains(@class,"filter_labe")]'))))
clickMe.click()
time.sleep(0)
clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//*[contains(@class,"filter_labe")])')))
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class,"filter_labe")]')

indexes = [index for index in range(len(options))]
shuffle(indexes)
for index in indexes:
    time.sleep(0)
    #driver.get('https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AS/B1/')
    clickMe1 = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//ul[@id="tournaments"]//li//input)[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
    clickMe1.click()
    time.sleep(0)
    ##tournaments > li > input
    #//*[@id='tournaments']//li//input

    # Team

#clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,("#mta_row td:nth-child(1)"))))
langs3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#mta_row   td:nth-child(1)")
langs3_text = []

for lang in langs3:
    print(lang.text)

    langs3_text.append(lang.text)
time.sleep(0)

# Team ODDS
langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#mta_row   .mpm_teams_cell_click:nth-child(2)   .mpm_teams_bet_val")
langs_text = []

for lang in langs:
    print(lang.text)
    langs_text.append(lang.text)
time.sleep(0)


# HREF
#langs2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='runners']//li[1]")
#a[href*="/sports/soccer/"]
#url1 = driver.current_url

#clickMe = wait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('.match-pop-market a[href*="/sports/soccer/"]'))))
clickMe = wait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ("//*[@class='match-pop-market']//a[href*='/sports/soccer/']"))))
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.match-pop-market a[href*="/sports/soccer/"]')
elem_href = []
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
    elem_href.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))


print(("NEW LINE BREAK"))
import sys
import io


with open('vtg121.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in zip(langs_text, langs3_text, elem_href):
        writer.writerow(row)
        print(row)
```

Comment: You have to use SO images.
And ask only one question per post especially if they are not related.

Comment: Post your code. Try to avoid using generic words like`webpage`, `here` etc. Be more specific. People may avoid you question if they have to visit several sites for that.

Comment: @salmanwahed Good point.  I posted my code

Comment: @HaydenDarcy please upload the image on SO, as it's a bad practice to rely on external services since your image will get deleted and the post unusable for future reference.

Comment: @Loïc Good point, I've removed all external links and put all relevant information in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is incorrect. Note that predicate like `[href*="/sports/soccer/"]` can be used in CSS selector while in XPath you should use `[contains(@href, "/sports/soccer/")]`. So complete line should be

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    clickMe = wait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='match-pop-market']//a[contains(@href, '/sports/soccer/')]")))
    clickMe1.click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("No link was found")
```

Comment: Yeah I adjusted that to: //div[contains(@class, 'match-pop-market')]//a[contains(@href, '/sports/soccer/')].  That works in inspection.  The error persists.  Odd.

Comment: Removing that line entirely seems to produce better results.  I assume the HRef is present in pages where selenium cannot find creating error

Comment: Then you can implement `try`/`except` block

Comment: That worked really well.   I do find it odd still how all the Selectors appear correct and yet it scrapes some pages and not others. https://ibb.co/i5weFm  [IMAGE] + code https://pastebin.com/PM3cKxBh .  I assume its trying to scrape from elements not appearing properly.. though does not explain why Href consistently gets scraped.